# I Just Go About My Business

Tags: riddle, rhyme

You might owe them an apology,
The saxophone can be a key,
I'm looking for a specific word,
It has one of the world's smallest turds.

If you find one, leave it be,
Feeding the world keeps it busy,
You can catch more flys with honey,
Steal their own and make your money..

Five syllables, and one short word,
Yes, my puzzle has a turd (ignore),
So timeless they have their own Latin root,
We study them, that we may have fruit.

Comment: This sounds interesting! It makes me hungry except for the, you know, turd stuff. :)

Comment: @Gerald Patriowski, Good luck. Well, I guess it's part of the cycle of life!

Comment: Sounds like fishing to me

Comment: @Avigrail, I hope not, but we'll see. Hopefully some of the puzzlers have access to Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The five-syllable word is

> **Apiology**

This definitely relates to

> **Honey bees** or other pollinators.

You might owe them an apology,

> We think of bees as annoying, but their role is critical.

The saxophone can be a key,

> The key of many saxophones is B-flat (thanks, @Arth)

I'm looking for a specific word,

> <s>Not sure here, perhaps ***Apoidea*** which is the taxonomic superfamily to which bees belong.</s>
>  Apiology

It has one of the world's smallest turds.

> <s>Maybe the "po" part of that word is like a really small "poo".</s>
>  Bees are small things.

If you find one, leave it be,

> Don't mess with the bee.

Feeding the world keeps it busy,

> Bees pollinate many flowering plants that we depend on for food.

You can catch more flys with honey,

> Many bees make honey.

Steal their own and make your money..

> Totally happens all the time.

Five syllables, and one short word,

> Apiology has 5 syllables and is relatively short.

Yes, my puzzle has a turd (ignore),

> Ignored, as directed.

So timeless they have their own Latin root,

> Apiology is from the Latin *api* = bee.

We study them, that we may have fruit.

> Understanding bees and their behavior/diseases is crucial to getting fruit, since bees must pollinate most fruit trees/plants.

And the question's title:

> Busy as a bee!

Comment: Bang. So can you go a little further and find the 5 syllable word?

Comment: @Dan_Russell, I think 'Apoidea' is only 4 syllables.

Comment: @John I think it's pronounced Ah-poe-ih-day-uh, but it sounds like it's not the one you're looking for. It also doesn't seem to match the turd and sax clues.

Comment: @John I searched for a while, but couldn't find anything that really fit. There are several -ologies that might be relevant, and several taxonomic ranks. Am I warm or should I be thinking of something else?

Comment: Could it be hymenopteran?

Comment: @Dan_Russell, so I don't think you could be much closer :). For world's smallest turd, it was just identifying a small creature. That's done. For saxophone, it's actually the same. A tenor sax is in set key. I'm new to this puzzling site and I hate misleading clues. Hopefully these don't qualify, but I'd like your input there.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdccuo7ko-8 for the pronunciation of your word.

Comment: Tenor and soprano saxes are also in the key of B flat.. which could help! Not too misleading, as I got this without your comment :)

Comment: @Arth, thank you. That makes me feel like it wasn't _too_ misleading. Maybe too much on identifying the critter and not enough on the word. I was cognizant of that when I posted it, but 1, 9, and 12 do address it specifically.

Comment: @John Does that mean Arth's suggestion above is correct?  I considered that, but it seemed a bit too broad.

Comment: @John, maybe a hint to tenor would have been useful for the sax clue as alto saxes are in a different pitch.

Comment: @DanRussell, absolutely. Arth is on _key_.... uggghhh.. I didn't just say that.

Comment: @Arth, definitely considered it. But would have felt compelled to remove 'key'.  I think that hint would be too strong, i.e. tenor, sax, and key in one line. But not really any more than the word 'be' I guess. Heard and noted Arth.  Thanks.

Comment: @John Fair enough.. still confused as to what the word is though!

Comment: @Arth, I will eat my crow if it's too obscure or difficult. But, 'apoidea' gave me hope. But, oddly enough, the word isn't on that wiki page, i.e. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apoidea.  However, I guarantee it could be... eh, maybe.

Comment: @John, aha, got it! Apiology! Very close to apology!

Comment: @Arth, Bang. So, any suggestions on the puzzle welcome. It was solved relatively quick I'd say though.

Comment: Googling 'study of bees' slaps you in the face with it!

Comment: Yeah, I considered that as well, but was looking for the things rather than the "study of" stuff.  (See my -ology comment above.)

Comment: @DanRussell, so did any of the clues throw you _off_ track? Just want to know for future reference.

Comment: @John I think the saxophone clue was totally fine, even though I didn't catch it.  The "little turd" one was the only one that I probably spent too much time on, but I do have the mindset of a sixth-grader, so I can come up with many turd synonyms.

Comment: @DanRussell, now that's funny. So, for posterity I also considered the world's 'stickiest' poop, :).  http://honeybeesuite.com/sticky-yellow-bee-droppings-are-a-good-thing/ But that might have resulted in a goose chase so I didn't. And, also just to clarify, I'm not an apiologist, and I did not know that about a honey bee's poop until I started putting this together. :)

Comment: "any suggestions on the puzzle welcome": some people don't like to use google when solving a riddle. In my opinion the best riddles have everything you'll need within their lines. Imagine someone wrote it down and took it with them to solve it with pen and paper.

Comment: @Avigrail, My opinion is that the _best_ riddles don't require Google as well. I would think that without using Google, one could deduce _bee_. At that point, 'looking for a specific word', and it has 'it's own latin root' should encourage the person to look further. A person is not required to look further, but only if they want to. Thanks for the feedback, but if you want the _best_ riddle, although I do _try_, you should probably steer clear of mine :).

Comment: @John Let's just go on with the fun of writing riddles! Maybe, one day, we will find the perfect riddle and make this sad world a little better :D

Comment: @Avigrail, hear hear.  My goal in life is to be resting with pen in hand and put the final period (or relevant character!) on the ultimate puzzle and peacefully pass away leaving the world with the most perfect riddle.  Well, not really, but it's not the worst way to go! :).